# How to - Make 1st dynamic dropdown MUST to select from 2nd dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here what am trying to do is this that - i have a working dynamic dropdown set from mysql tables. I am trying to make 1st dropdown compulsory, to choose any options from 2nd dropdown. I am trying to pass selected option value from 1st dropdown, in 2nd dropdown change function & check if its empty.

But no success yet. Here is the Code:

```
      <!doctype html>
      <html>
      <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <title>Untitled Document</title>

          <script type="text/javascript">

              $(document).ready(function (e) {

                  $("#cat").change(function one () {

                      var textval = $(":selected", this).html();
                      var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value

                      if (url) { // require a URL
                          window.location = 'page.php?cat=' + url + '&subcat=' + textval; // redirect
                      }

                     // store value of selected option in url. This value be paseed on to below function two();

                     // function two(url);

                  }) // cat change function ends

                  $("#subcat").change(function two() {

                      var numval = $(":selected", this).val();
                      //$("#aid").val(numval);

                      var textval2 = $(":selected", this).html();
                      //$('input[name=villa-name]').val(textval2);

                      window.location = window.location.href + '&subcat=' + numval;


                  })

              });


          </script>


      </head>
      <body>
      </body>
      </html>
```

Thanks in Advance. Still wondering how to do this in jQuery ?

Comment: change event in dd1 id doing smthing like changing url of page, but that is not my concern. My issue is - if i select 2nd dropdown options without selecting 1st drop dow, it must not be allowed. Now, if nothing is selected from dd1, it means that it is empty, then dd2 must not be allowed or give alert

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#subcat").attr("disabled", "disabled");

$("#cat").change(function() {
  if ($("#cat option:selected").val() !== "---") {
    $("#subcat").removeAttr("disabled")
  } else {
    $("#subcat").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="cat">
  <option value="---">Select one</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>

<select id="subcat">
  <option value="---">Select another</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

Also, I'm assuming you want the contents of the second drop down to depend on the choice of the first dropdown. It seems like you're handling this logic server side. If you continue with that route, you could just have the second drop down disabled on the initial page load by adding a `disabled="disabled"` attribute to the subcategory element server side.

What I would recommend instead, because it avoids a full-page refresh, is to either have the server include a populated JavaScript object with all the possible categories and subcategories when the page loads, *or* adding an AJAX endpoint to request subcategories when the main category changes.

The first option would have the server include something like the following in the response:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var categories = [
    {
        name: 'Category 1',
        value: 'cat1',
        children: [
            { name: 'Subcategory 1', value: 'sub1' },
            { name: 'Subcategory 2', value: 'sub2' },
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'Category 2',
        value: 'cat2',
        children: [
            { name: 'Subcategory 3', value: 'sub3' },
            { name: 'Subcategory 4', value: 'sub4' },
        ]
    }
];
</script>
```

... so you could then change the above example to populate `#cat` from this array, and `#subcat` based on `$('#cat option:selected').val()`. Something like the following:

```js
$("#cat").html('<option value="---">Select one</option>');
$("#subcat").html('<option value="---">Select another</option>');
$("#subcat").attr("disabled", "disabled");

categories.forEach(function(cat) {
  var $cat = $("<option />")
    .val(cat.value)
    .html(cat.name);
  $("#cat").append($cat);
});

$("#cat").change(function() {
  
    
  $("#subcat .subcat").remove();
  $("#subcat").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  
  var $selectedCategory = $('#cat option:selected');
  
  if ($selectedCategory.val() !== "---") {
    
    $("#subcat").removeAttr("disabled");
    
    var cat = categories.find(function(cat) {
      return cat.value === $selectedCategory.val();
    });
    
    if (cat.hasOwnProperty('children')) {
      
      cat.children.forEach(function(subcat) {
        
        var $subcat = $('<option class="subcat" />')
          .val(subcat.value)
          .html(subcat.name);
        $("#subcat").append($subcat);
        
      });
      
    }
    
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var categories = [
    {
        name: 'Category 1',
        value: 'cat1',
        children: [
            { name: 'Subcategory 1', value: 'sub1' },
            { name: 'Subcategory 2', value: 'sub2' },
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'Category 2',
        value: 'cat2',
        children: [
            { name: 'Subcategory 3', value: 'sub3' },
            { name: 'Subcategory 4', value: 'sub4' },
        ]
    }
];
</script>

<select id="cat"></select>

<select id="subcat"></select>
```

Comment: Nicely done. It makes me happy to see that you used javascript to set the initial value of `disabled` as well. A lot of people forget about graceful degradation and puts the attribute in the HTML, making the form useless if javascript breaks for some reason on page load.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but if you're trying to build an URL from the selected value of your two drop down lists, you can do something like this.

```
var catWasSelected = false;
$("#cat").change(function() {
     catWasSelected = true;
});

$("#subcat").change(function() {
     if(catWasSelected){
         var cat = $("#cat").val();
         var subcat = $("#subcat").val();
         window.location = 'page.php?cat=' + cat + '&subcat=' + subcat;
     }else{
         // set the subcategory back to default
         // something like: $("#subcat").val("default");
         alert("Please select a category");
     }
});
```